# D3 how do I start my y-axis at something other than 0

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, axis-labels

I have a dual axis graph like this

[image]

the 2 Y axis are not optimally scaled Ideally for the 
-Right hand Y I would like to start at 1.5 and end at 4 ticks at .1
-Left hand Y I would Like to start at 50 and end a 60 ticks at 1

how does one do that here is my code and data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<title>Self Identification Percentages</title>
<style>
.dataDisplay {
  font-size:1em;
}


body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}



</style>

 <script src="./jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./jquery.corner.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script src="./d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>








<div id="graph"></div>

<script>


// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 1]);
var yr = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 1]);


// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(10);
var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("right").ticks(10); 

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.pctgDiff); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data


 var dataFile = "abo.csv";
 d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.pctgDiff = d.pctgDiff;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "#7CA2C8");


    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);


    // Add the Y Axis
    //svg.append("g")
    //    .attr("class", "y axis")
    //    .call(yAxis);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -40)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .style("font-size", "12px")
          .style("font-weight", "900")
          .style("font", "sans-serif")
      .text("All Other Change");


 });





 dataFile = "dis.csv";
 d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.pctgDiff = d.pctgDiff;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "#ECAD6F");
 });



 dataFile = "min.csv";
 d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.pctgDiff = d.pctgDiff;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "#C3D1DC");
 });



 dataFile = "fem.csv";
 d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.pctgDiff = d.pctgDiff;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "#7CC8A2");

   svg.append("g")             
        .attr("class", "y axis")    
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")   
        .style("fill", "#7CC8A2")       
        .call(yAxisRight);
  svg.append("g")
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 310)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .style("font-size", "12px")
          .style("font-weight", "900")
          .style("font", "sans-serif")
      .style("fill", "#7CC8A2") 
      .text("Female Change");
 });

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I have tried fiddling with

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 1]);
var yr = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 1]);

changing the 0 to a 1 for instance yet it still starts at the origin for both sides

here is my data too:

abo.csv:

```
date,pctgDiff
2014-03-31,1.850000
2015-03-31,2.400000
2016-03-31,2.700000
2016-11-10,3.280000
```

dis.csv:

```
date,pctgDiff
2014-03-31,1.020000
2015-03-31,1.040000
2016-03-31,1.170000
2016-11-10,1.320000
```

min.csv

```
date,pctgDiff
2014-03-31,5.010000
2015-03-31,6.100000
2016-03-31,6.370000
```

2016-11-10,6.070000

fem.csv

```
date,pctgDiff
2014-03-31,53.540000
2015-03-31,53.940000
2016-03-31,54.510000
2016-11-10,54.830000
```

Comment: Change the y axis domain from `y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);` to something like `y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);` or set a value yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks Paul y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; }), 6.51]); worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaking range and domain. The range corresponds to the extent in pixels, the domain to the extent in whatever your scale is supposed to deal with.

Comment: y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; }), 6.51]); looks like it will do it for me thanks Lorem

Answer (score 5):

Y axis build method uses array of start and end values. `domain` method in your case get 0 as start point.

> y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; })]);

You can use your custom value instead of 0 or just use 
 `d3.extent(array[, accessor])` helper method to get `[minimum, maximum]` array for your current data.

> **d3.extent(array[, accessor])**
>
> Returns the minimum and maximum value in the given array using natural
>   order. If the array is empty, returns [undefined, undefined]. An
>   optional accessor function may be specified, which is equivalent to
>   calling array.map(accessor) before computing the extent.

**Example:**

y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; }));

Comment: thanks Enver!  that got me going y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.pctgDiff; }), 6.51]);